# Geometric sequence, where n is increased by 2 each time

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the sequence $P(Ω) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 1/n^2 $ ,but n must be increased by 2 each time. How do I actually solve that?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "n must be increased by 2 each time"? Do you mean $P(\Omega) = 1 + 1/3^2 + 1/5^2+ ...$?

Comment: yes, this is what I mean. sorry for not putting it as clearly as I should, im not very familiar with mathematical expression in English

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see (incl. proof) [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem), we have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

and

\begin{align*}
1 + \frac{1}{3^2} + \frac{1}{5^2}+ \ldots  & = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k-1)^2} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} - \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k)^2} \\
& = \frac{\pi^2}{6} - \frac{1}{4} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} - \frac{\pi^2}{24} = \frac{\pi^2}{8}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

[If I understood your questions correctly and you know Riemann zeta-function of 2]:

$$
\sum_{k} \frac{1}{k^2} = \sum_{k} \frac{1}{(2k-1)^2} + \sum_{k} \frac{1}{(2k)^2}
$$

Can you handle from here?

Comment: umm, i cant say that i can. and i dont know this function. This task was part of a probability question and Im not good with sequences to begin with..

Comment: then you need to explain what you meant by 'n must increase by 2 every time'

Comment: ok, n= 1,3,5,7,.... till infinity.

Comment: Then my solution stands: you know the expression on LHS, obtain after a bit of algebra the second sum on the RHS and you got the result as a function of $P$